# Finding elements of order $8$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{8000000}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I want to find elements of order $8$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{8000000}$.

I know that elements of order $n$ in a group $\mathbb{Z}_m$ is $\phi(n)$. But how can I apply this result for a group having such a large number of elements?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Do you want to find the elements, or do you want to find the number of them?

Comment: I want to find their number. Is it possible to find elements as well in this case?

Comment: Note that the order of the group only enters into the number of elements of a given order when determining if such elements exist (for cyclic groups like this), since the number of elements of order $n$ is $\varphi(n)$ in that case, independent of the order of the group.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Can you write in the answer with little more explanation?

Comment: It is also possible to find the element explicitly, by noting that if a cyclic group is generated by $g$ of order $n$ and $m$ divides $n$ then $g^m$ has order $\frac{n}{m}$ and any element of order $\frac{n}{m}$ is a power of $g^m$.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I got my answer. I was confused little bit. Thanks.

Comment: Is this question about *additive* groups or *multiplicative*, cyclic groups?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since $Z_{8000000}$ is cyclic, it contains exactly $\phi(8)=4$ elements of order $8$. We see that $1000000\in Z_{8000000}$ is one of these elements. It is also the generator of the unique subgroup of $Z_{8000000}$ of order $8$. The other three elements of order $8$ are $7000000$, $5000000$, and $3000000$. In general, the generators of this unique subgroup are the elements $n\cdot
 1000000$, where $\gcd(n,8)=1$.

NOTE: $\phi(8000000)$ would be the number of generators of $Z_{8000000}$. We calculate $\phi(8)$ because we are interested in the number of generators of the subgroup of $Z_{8000000}$ of size $8$ as opposed to the whole group, which is size $8000000$.

Comment: @monalisa, does the edit answer your question?

Comment: Ah it completely answer my question. My doubt is cleared. Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: Happy to help! :)

Comment: Thanks again for the help . :)

Comment: Are we talking about cyclic, multiplicative groups here? Because then this answer is just wrong; $1000000^2 \equiv 0$.

Comment: @TMM, I believe we are taking about subgroups of the additive integers.

Answer (score 3):

The order of $\bar m$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{8000000}$ is $\frac{8000000}{gcd(m,8000000)}$. This is $8$ if and only if

$$gcd(m,8000000)=1000000$$

Thus, $m$ must be an odd multiple of $1000000$.

Answer (score 0):

There are $4$ elements of order $8$. This is because Φ(8)=4, and these elements are $1,3,5,7$. So the generators of $8000000$ of order $8$ are $1000000,3000000,5000000$ and $7000000$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).